# update a column inside a stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two snowflake tables as below

TEST1

```
create OR REPLACE table TEST1 (
  id varchar(100), 
  name varchar(100),
  org VARCHAR(64)
);    

INSERT INTO TEST1 values (100, 'ABC', null);
INSERT INTO TEST1 values (200, 'XYZ', null);
INSERT INTO TEST1 values (300, 'VBN', null);
```

CONTROL

```
create OR REPLACE table CONTROL (
  KEY_COLUMNS VARCHAR,
  TABLE_NAME VARCHAR,
  org VARCHAR
);    

INSERT INTO CONTROL values ('id,name, address','TEST1','Z');
INSERT INTO CONTROL values ('id,name, address','TEST2','T');
```

I have created a stored procedure which updates column 'org' in TEST1 table with the values from CONTROL table (column org) where table name is TEST1.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST(source_tbl VARCHAR) 
    RETURNS string
    LANGUAGE SQL
    AS
    $$  
    DECLARE
           query1 STRING;
     BEGIN
           QUERY1 := 'update TEST1  set ORG = (select org from CONTROL WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''source_tbl'');';

           EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :QUERY1;

           RETURN :QUERY1;
      END;
      $$;
call TEST((select TABLE_NAME from CONTROL WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TEST1'));
```

expected output

[image]

My output

[image]

Comment: `call TEST((select TABLE_NAME from CONTROL WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TEST1'));` that's wild. Didn't know you could do that without throwing an error. What happens when more than one result is returned from the inner sql?

Comment: @JNevill " What happens when more than one result is returned from the inner sql?" A standard error "Single-row subquery returns more than one row."

Comment: Thanks @LukaszSzozda That's good to know!

Answer (score 0):

The parameter should be bound variable instead of passing as  the string constant `''source_tbl''`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST(source_tbl VARCHAR) 
RETURNS string
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$  
DECLARE
   query1 STRING;
BEGIN
  QUERY1 := 'update TEST1 set ORG = (select org from CONTROL WHERE TABLE_NAME = ?);';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :QUERY1 USING (SOURCE_TBL);

  RETURN :QUERY1;
END;
$$
```

Related: [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/execute-immediate.html#):

> ```
> EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '<string_literal>'
>  [ USING (bind_variable_1 [, bind_variable_2 ...] ) ] ;
> ```